# In Javascript, how to import an array from another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, import

```
//level1.js

[[1,2,3,0,0],
[0,0,0,4,0],
[0,4,2,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,3,0]];
```

I'm making a game and I want this array of arrays to be imported into my game.js file. (To be able to choose the map)

```
//game.js

let map = "level1"

import * as gameBoard from `./${map}.js`
```

Comment: You are not exporting anything from `level1.js`. And I think that you can't use template strings for `import` statements.

Comment: @VLAZ so how should I do?

Answer (score 7):

You need to export your array in level1.js.

```
  //level1.js

  export const array = [
    [1,2,3,0,0],
    [0,0,0,4,0],
    [0,4,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,3,0]
  ];
```

And then you can import the variable from game.js

```
//game.js
import { array } from './level1.js'
```

Comment: It says "Cannot use import statement outside a module" :/

Comment: You need to use ES6 for the solution above. Otherwise you have to use module exports

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this links https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import,
It will help U.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running your scripts using "node script.js",then you're gonna have to use the "exports/require" method:

- In level1.js:

```js
exports.array = [1, 2, 3];
```

- In game.js:

```js
const level1 = require('./level1');
    
// then access it like so
console.log(level1.array);
```

If, however, you wanted to use the "import" syntax that the guys are suggesting above, then you're gonna have to enable ES6 syntax.